# Raspberry pi camera module issue OSError

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, picamera

I am trying to run Raspberry Pi camera module on Raspberry Pi 3 Model
B using Python but I am getting this error:

```
OSError: libmmal.so: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

Comment: 1 - check that pi camera is installed with pip3
otherwise install the `pip3 install --user picamera` or `sudo apt-get install python3-picamera`  2 - which OS do you use ?

Comment: same issue face, when I disable camera with raspi-config and try libcamera-still -t 0 -o test.jpg command, it works, but on legacy camera support, libcamera-still -t 0 -o test.jpg did not work,

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Raspbian distro, you probably have picamera installed by default. You can find out simply by starting Python and trying to import picamera:

Referenced

https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/

Comment: This answer has no relevance to the question.